# Ease-in and ease-out with Vector2.MoveTowards

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've seen a lot of examples of easing with `Vector2.Lerp`.

But I want to use `Vector2.MoveTowards` because I am randomizing the distance my NPC is traveling, and I want the speed of the NPC to always be constant regardless of the distance traveled. Ideally, would like to control the easing granularly with an `AnimationCurve` if that's possible, but a smooth step function would be ok too. Here is the simplified code that I'm using now (using Behavior Designer so the methods are a bit different):

```
    private readonly float Speed = 1.5f;
    public SharedVector2 BugDirection;
    
    public override void OnStart()
    {
       BugDirection.Value = new Vector2(Random.Range(0.1f, 0.5f), transform.position.y);
    }

    public override TaskStatus OnUpdate()
    {
        if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, BugDirection.Value) == 0)
        {
            return TaskStatus.Success;
        }

       transform.position = 
           Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, BugDirection.Value, Speed * Time.deltaTime);
        
       return TaskStatus.Running;
    }
```

Comment: Could you post your current code? How exactly are you moving the objects so far?

Comment: Sure I have added the code to my post.

Comment: you can look into [`Vector2.SmoothDamp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.SmoothDamp.html) for at least have ease-out .. with your current approach however it is hard to tell when exactly a new movement should begin ...

Comment: So I have tried this approach to calculate when the ease in/out should begin but it didn't work correctly:
    `private float GenerateTimeToReachDestination()
    {
        float Distance = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, BugDirection.Value);
        return Distance / Speed;
    }`

And in Update I had this logic:
        `CurrentTime += Time.deltaTime;
        float CurrentSpeed = AnimationMovementCurve.Evaluate(CurrentTime/TimeToReachDestination);`

Didn't work though, not even close, even when I pulled the logic out into a coroutine. (Sorry for the weird formatting)

Comment: Well the main question as said is: How exactly do you know when a new movement starts and when it ends? Is the `BugDirection` changed continuously?

Comment: Yeah that is a good point that I left that piece out. I was trying to keep my question generic because my actual logic is utilizing Behavior Designer, but I have updated my code to reflect when the NPC stops. Hope it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okey so there is one first issue: **Never** use `==` for comparing two `float` values!

Even a situation like `5f * 0.2f / 10f == 1f` might **fail** because due to floating point precision it might actually be `0.9999999` or `1.0000001`.

Instead you usually rather check against a certain range like e.g.

```
if(Mathf.Abs(a - b) <= someThreshold)
```

Unity for this also offers [`Mathf.Approximately`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html) and using

```
if(Mathf.Approximately(a, b))
```

basically equals using

```
if(Mathf.Abs(a - b) <= Mathf.Epsilon)
```

where [`Epsilon`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Epsilon.html) is

> The smallest value that a float can have different from zero.

So much for your current stop condition.

---

I just assume for now this is happening somewhere outside of a `MonoBehaviour` so a Coroutine would not be an option.

However, what you basically want to achieve is having a value that continously grows from `0` to `1` linear (the time) mapped onto an eased-in and eased-out movement curve.

So assuming that the target position is **not updated** between the start and the ending of a movement I would do it like e.g.

```
private readonly float Speed = 1.5f;

private Vector2 target;
private Vector2 start;
private float timePassed;
private float duration;

public override void OnStart()
{
   target = new Vector2(Random.Range(0.1f, 0.5f), transform.position.y);
   start = transform.position;

   duration = Vector2.Distance(start, target) / speed;
   timePassed = 0f;
}

public override TaskStatus OnUpdate()
{
    if (timePassed >= duration)
    {
        transform.position = target;
        return TaskStatus.Success;
    }

    var factor = timePassed / duration;

    //MAGIC

    transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(start, target, factor);

   timePassed += Time.deltaTime;
    
   return TaskStatus.Running;
}
```

So far this will be a linear movement just as before ;)

So let's fill in the `MAGIC`.

One very simple option for ease-in and ease-out is using [`Mathf.SmoothStep`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.SmoothStep.html) like e.g.

```
factor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, factor);
```

or you could give the [`AnimationCurve`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationCurve.html) another shot now using

```
factor = yourAnimationCurve.Evaluate(factor);
```

which gives you complete control over the smoothing of the movement and yet results in the total average velocity of `speed` as if you would have applied it linear.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I will look into refactoring my code, and have removed the problematic float comparison.